# Early expansion of \newcommand or another macro-like statement

Tags: macros, arguments

I would like to store a list of arguments within `\newcommand`, `\def` or any other macro. Such a list would then be passed to another command. However, it turns out that the list in question is treated as a single argument by the other command. Example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\nodestyle}{scale=2, color=blue}
% \def\nodestyle{scale=2, color=blue}
\newcommand{\customnode}{\node[circle ee, draw, \nodestyle]}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \customnode at (1,1) (Node) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces an error *I do not know the key /tikz/scale=2, color=blue*.

Comment: You can also use a bucket load of `\expandafter`s.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you could but I'm so modern I'm prepared to use features added in the early 90's.

Comment: Why not using TikZ styles?

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea.  (I did test it.)

Comment: You can also do `style/.expand once=\nodestyle` but indeed, why not use a style? That's why they exist.

Comment: @egreg your solution is what I will actually use in this concrete case, but I also wanted to know a generic way of handling macros like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pre-expand the argument, `expl3` is designed for such expansion control but here just using the (e)tex primitive

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\nodestyle}{scale=2, color=blue}
% \def\nodestyle{scale=2, color=blue}
\newcommand{\customnode}{\expanded{\noexpand\node[circle ee, draw, \nodestyle]}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \customnode at (1,1) (Node) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the native method.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.gates.ee}

\tikzset{
  nodestyle/.style={scale=2,color=blue},
}
\newcommand{\customnode}{\node[circle ee,draw,nodestyle]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \customnode at (1,1) (Node) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```